# Build own REST API that calls third party REST API to return specific query

Tags: api, rest

so I've made a REST-exposed backend implemented in NodeJS with persistent storage in MongoDB and also know how to call third party API as a client but how to create my own endpoints that call this third party API's endpoints such that I use the results from this third party REST API to answer queries?

Comment: Sounds like you have all the pieces, what did you try putting them together?

Comment: I think I might consume third party api inside my custom made api. will be touch in due course. if it works, I'll post the answer on here.